# run two file.py one after the other in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, jupyter-notebook, schedule

I am using jupyter notebook.

I have this two files with two scripts: script1.py and script2.py

While file script1.py runs every minutes in a while loop, I would like to run script2.py 4 minutes after running script.1, in the same loop.

This is what I have so far: A script that runs script1.py every minute in a loop with one minute sleep time.

```
starttime=time.time()

while True:
     %run "script1.py"
     time.sleep(60.0 - ((time.time() - starttime) % 60.0))
```

Where can I add %run "script2.py" to this code?

Comment: you should look into your OS’ schedulers because this is not a good approach

Comment: Please clarify you needs. Should it run before 5th execution of script2? After? Simultaneously?

Comment: @Slam yes, I meant something like run before 5th execution of script1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if it's been 4 minutes, and run script2 if it has:

```
starttime=time.time()

 while True:
     %run "script1.py"

     if (time.time() - starttime) >= 240.0
         %run "script2.py"

     time.sleep(60.0 - ((time.time() - starttime) % 60.0))
```

Comment: then it would run on every subsequent run right away, so after 4 minutes it will run every time right after script 1

Answer (score 1):

perhaps you could do something like

```
starttime= time.time()

while True:
    %run "script1.py"
    time.sleep(60.0 - ((time.time() - starttime) % 60.0))
    if( (starttime - time.time()) > 240): %run "script2.py"
```

Comment: I understand where you're going with this but consider adding the entire script so we have a workable example.

Comment: @Duke you mean the code can be  `starttime= time.time() while True:
     %run "script1.py"
     time.sleep(60.0 - ((time.time() - starttime) % 60.0)) while True:
    if( (starttime - time.time()) > 240): %run "script2.py" ` ?